# C library for email composition with UTF-8 characters

Tags: c, utf-8, smtp, diacritics

I'm building a C app that must send email containing UTF-8 (accented) characters in the body.  I found 285 related postings on stackoverflow but they don't address my specific questions:

1. Is there a C library (not windows/platform specific) to help compose an email, then send by SMTP?  (I don't want to just call a shell command from C).  I found chilkat libraries but they look overwhelming.
2. Is it possible to put UTF-8 characters into a plaintext email?  If not, how would I send UTF-8 characters in the body?
3. If I send an HTML based email body, does a plaintext version automatically get created (or is this a function of the mail client presenting the email to the recipient).

Thanks@

Comment: Regarding point 2, have you read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html ? Simply put, "plain text" means nothing, so yes, you can put UTF-8 characters in your email. Just tell the other side you are using UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention an operating system. the c-client library from ftp://ftp.cac.washington.edu/imap/ (called "imap" there) has function to encode mails and should work on different Unix flavors and Windows. Even though the version number says 2007 it's updated this year. The tarball contains some documentation. ftp://ftp.cac.washington.edu/imap/imap-2007f.tar.gz

Comment: I found the U Washington library but it appears to be a mess (a poorly documented dump of functions).  Hoping for something better...thx

Comment: Yes it is a mess. I didn't find anything better, yet. While I didn't actively search for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put `Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` and `Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable` in the header (for the message or MIME part, depending on if you're using multiple MIME parts), and encode the *byte stream* of UTF-8 as quoted-printable (the ugly `=XX` stuff). There's nothing UTF-8-specific to be done.